# How to limit number of wireless clients on Cisco access point?

Tags: cisco, access-point, cisco-wireless

We have a Cisco access point in autonomous mode. Is there a way we can set a limit on the number of simultaneous wireless clients either per-radio or per-SSID on the access point? If yes, what is the command?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do that. It is called `max-associations` option under `ssid` configuration section and can be done per SSID.

Let us say you want to set the maximum number of devices that can associate using `your_ssid` to 5:

```
# conf t   
(config)# dot11 ssid your_ssid      
(config-ssid)# max-associations 5
(config-ssid)# end
```

You can check more details at [Configuration Guide for Autonomous Aironet AP](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/15-3-3/configuration/guide/cg15-3-3/cg15-3-3-chap7-mbssid.html?bookSearch=true) and [Cisco Aironet AP FAQ](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/wireless/aironet-1200-series/8103-ap-faq.html)